# AngularJS: Add function result within ngclick

Tags: angularjs

Unfortunately, I do not know, how to even start.
Basically, I got my scope, with multiple entries. Now, I would like to add additional nodes dynamically. While adding those I would like to add a UUID/GUID at the same time.

So a bit of very basic, pseudo code:

`<button ng-click="entries.unshift({'title': "dummy", 'uuid': getUuid()})">Add item</button>`

A click on that button should add

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "title": "dummy",
      "uuid": "7878ceb8-f152-4029-91f6-bf25086a1461"
    },
    {
      "title": "dummy",
      "uuid": "7878ceb8-f152-4029-91f6-bf25086a1461"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally the UUID is coming from a different function

```
function getUuid() {
  // here comes some code - but that is available
  return "7878ceb8-f152-4029-91f6-bf25086a1461";
}
```

Any idea to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the problem with your *pseudo code*?

Comment: Assuming that the object wrapping around "entries" is $scope, your pseudocode should work fine. If not, just prepend the object reference before entries

Comment: The code will work fine, what is the problem?

Comment: you are right... I needed to add it to the scope...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the function to scope - then it works:

```
$scope.getUuid = function() {
    return "abcdefg";
};
```

Comment: Any data or functions you are accessing from templates need to be exposed on scope.